# View not being injected in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple Angular app and I have recently added a router in route.js. For some reason the association isn't being made between `mainCtrl` and `someview.html` The reason I know this is because the view isn't being injected in `<div ng-view></div>` Anyone have any idea why?

My folder structure is the following

```
root
------/app
----------routes.js
----------/views
-----------------someview.html
------/public
---------mainCtrl.js
---------index.html
server.js
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP',[])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Artists = [
      {name:"Blink 182",age:14},
      {name:"Led Zeppelin",age:12},
      {name:"Lil Wayne",age:11}
    ];
    $scope.number = 100;
});
```

**someview.html**

```
<div>{{number}}</div>
```

**route.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/views/someview.html',
    controller  : 'MainCtrl'
  })

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='LiveAPP'> 
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mainCtrl.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Listening at 3000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('LiveAPP',[])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
```

Here, you define a module LiveAPP, that doesn't depend on any other module, and add a controller to this module.

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

And here, you redefine, once again, a module with the same name, depending on ngRoute. But since you're redefining it, you effectively overwrite the previously defined module and all its components.

A module must be defined once, and only once.

I don't know much about express, but I also don't understand why all your files are not under `public`, since that is apparently the directory that the web server serves.